# Reopen question to give general answer (duped is too specific)

Tags: support, questions, duplicate-questions, specific-question, vote-to-reopen

I recently [asked a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25020713/multiple-inheritance-ambiguous-method-definitions) about Python multiple inheritance which was duped to a [more specific case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277367/how-does-pythons-super-work-with-multiple-inheritance). In my opinion, for the benefit of those who come after us, the question should be reopened and answered in the general case. The duped question is too specific to be of use to people searching on the situation in my question.

I'll happily be the one to answer, so long as the question is reopened. Thanks.

Comment: You should be editing the question to make it crystal clear to readers why it is different from the duplicate.  Also make sure that you've looked through the duplicate thoroughly, often you'll find a rather narrow and specific title with a well generalized answer.

Comment: So, do you want your close reason to be switched to **too broad** instead?

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer of the linked duplicate focuses entirely on MRO; the fact that `super()` is mentioned when your own question doesn't use it is rather accidental. The questions have the same answer. (Not voting to reopen, or rather unilaterally reopen-hammering. Martijn is, as usual, correct.)